# Join to Connect Objects together

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, transforms

I made a Gameboy with different objects and modifiers.

I want to move it the side but somehow all objects separate as I move. I want to join the objects together.

Comment: could you please add some screenshots and please post your .blend file

Comment: you can join several objects with Ctrl J, you can also parent them to a parent object or to a parent empty with Ctrl P

Comment: can you add the link here and i will upload it as i'm new to this?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/